# rails has_many manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I'm attempting to create a polymorphic imaging system which would allow various objects to have a cover image and additional images. Would I be correct in creating an `Image` model with `belongs_to :imageable` ? Or, should I separate out my logic so each model that will inherit image capabilities be given a separate polymorphic associations for both cover images and additional images?

Then, once I have setup has_many relationship, how do I manage it? In a perfect world I would want to be able to call `@object.images.cover?` and `@object.images.additionals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `images` table for your polymorphic association that has a `cover` boolean field, indicating if the image in the record is a cover image:

```
create_table :images do |t|
  t.boolean :cover, :default => false
  t.references :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  t.timestamps
end
```

Then include `has_many :images, :as => :imageable` on your objects. Now to have the `@object.cover` and `@object.additionals` that you desire, you have two options. The first is to create a Concern module to mix-in to your Object classes. The second is to subclass. I'll talk about the Concern approach here because it is a method being pushed in Rails 4, and subclassing is already familiar to most programmers.

Create a module inside `app/models/concerns`:

```
module Imageable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :images, :as => :imageable # remove this from your model file
  end

  def cover
    images.where(:cover => true).first
  end

  def additionals
    images.where(:cover => false).all
  end
end
```

You can now mix-in this concern to your object classes. For example:

```
class Object1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Imageable

  ...
end
```

You will also have to include your concerns from `app/models/concerns`, since they won't be loaded automatically (in Rails 4, any file in that directory will be included by default).

Comment: +1 for the concern approach, but... <troll>what if multiple imageables have the same images, and want a different cover ? </troll>

Comment: How are you using those methods?

Comment: Ah, figured out the problem, I need to be calling object.cover instead of object.images.cover. Does this make sense? When I call object.images it just returns an array of all the images found from the has_many relationship

Comment: Ah, that is right... in this implementation, those methods are added directly to your object classes. If you want them attached to images, they should be added/mixed-in to your Image class, not the object class.